# Using WPF/MVVM, how do I pass the SelectedIndex value of a Listbox to my ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need to take the currently SelectedIndex of a Listbox and pass the index number to my ViewModel. That index number is then used to access a specific object in a list of objects which is then used as part of a formula. Most examples I've looked at recommend using SelectedItem instead of SelectedIndex, but the Listbox is comprised of bitmap images so I'm not really sure how that would work.

Here's an example of how things are supposed to work:

- user selects one of the images, let's say the very first one, so SelectedIndex would be equal to 0.
- the value of 0 gets passed to the ViewModel which has a List of "Record" objects.
- since 0 was passed, the first object in the list is accessed and one of its properties is used in a formula.

This seems like a pretty straightforward thing to do, but my novice experience in MVVM and WPF has me a bit stumped.

Comment: Hello you can keep integer property in your view model, publin int SelectedRecordIndex {get;set;} for example. In your ListBox you should set SelectedIndex = "{Binding SelectedRecordIndex }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can bind a property(let's assume it's called SelectedIdx) in ViewModel to SelectedIndex , Binding Mode can chose OneWayToSourc ,or TwoWay.

So,when you selected one item,your viewModel will get the selectedIndex through SelecteIdx.

Comment: Ok this works. Is there a way to also update another property at the same time? So if I have a label that is bound to a property called CurrentRecord, can CurrentRecord change to be equal to Record[SelectedIndex].Name and then have the label update as soon as the user clicks the picture? I can't figure out how to force the label to update once a new picture is clicked. The ViewModel already implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: You can implement a command for the selected item. Have a property called RecordInView, and than you pass the SelectedItem to this property.
Another solution is to bind the selected item to a property and set this property to be shown on another field.

Comment: Note that you don't need to explicitly set the Binding Mode. The SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedIndex properties of an ItemsControl bind TwoWay by default.